# Analysing frames from a video file using EMGU 3.0.0 in visual basic 2013

Tags: vba, video, video-capture, emgucv

I have been using EMGU 2.9.0 in the Visual basic environment to open a video file,  read the frames sequentially, analyse them and close the video.

This was accomplished by:

```
Private Sub BW_SBD_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BW_SBD.DoWork
    'Background Worker - Do Work Thread

    Dim currentFrame As New Image(Of Gray, Byte)(FrameHeight, FrameWidh) 'Declare image objects to hold current and previous frame 
    Dim frameCount As Integer = 1
    Dim numFrames As Integer  'number of frame for the video

    For Each file As String In lstbSelectedVideoList.Items
        ' For Each file As String In files - Loop through the list of files 
        Dim previousFrame As New Image(Of Gray, Byte)(FrameHeight, FrameWidh)

        Using fingerprintCapture As New Capture(file)  ' Create a capture from file 
            numFrames = CType(Math.Round(fingerprintCapture.GetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)), Integer)     ' Get video's total number of frames

            frameCount = 1

            fingerprintCapture.SetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)                                   ' Jump to start frame
            currentFrame = fingerprintCapture.QueryGrayFrame()                                                          ' get a frame

            While fingerprintCapture.GetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) < 0.0                          ' Make sure the start frame was found (codecs create problems with the set frame pos function)
                currentFrame = fingerprintCapture.QueryGrayFrame()                                                      ' get a frame
            End While

            While currentFrame IsNot Nothing

            'The analysis procedure requires the frames from the video
                If MyFrameAnalysisFunction(currentFrame, previousFrame) = 1 Then
                    MessageBox.Show('This part is irrelevant')
                End If


                previousFrame = currentFrame.Clone()               ' Update frame objects by saving previous frame and querying a new one
                currentFrame = fingerprintCapture.QueryGrayFrame() ' get new frame

                frameCount += 1
            End While

        End Using
    Next
End Sub
```

When updating the code to the newer version of Emgu 3.0.0, I have been struggling to get it to work again.  It seems that the new version has moved away from working with Image classes and prefer the Mat class.

The updated code compiles but the frames I try to retrieve stays NOTHING.  The adapted code is as follow:

```
    Private Sub BW_JSD_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BW_JSD.DoWork
    Dim CurrentFrameMAT As New Mat()

    Dim frameCount As Integer = 1
    Dim numFrames As Integer                                                 ' video identifier, percentage complete, and number of frame for the video

    Dim filenr As Long = 0

    For Each file As String In lstbAnalysisList.Items
        Dim previousFrameMAT As New Mat()

        filenr += 1

        Using fingerprintCapture As New Capture(file)                                                                   ' Create a capture from file 
            numFrames = CType(Math.Round(fingerprintCapture.GetCaptureProperty(CapProp.FrameCount)), Integer)     ' Get video's total number of frames

            frameCount = 1

            fingerprintCapture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.PosFrames, 0)                                   ' Jump to start frame
            CurrentFrameMAT = fingerprintCapture.QueryFrame()

            While fingerprintCapture.GetCaptureProperty(CapProp.PosFrames) < 0.0                          ' Make sure the start frame was found (codecs create problems with the set frame pos function)
                CurrentFrameMAT = fingerprintCapture.QueryFrame()
            End While

            While CurrentFrameMAT IsNot Nothing                                                                            

                If MyFrameAnalysisFunction(currentFrameMAT, previousFrameMAT) = 1 Then
                    MessageBox.Show('This part is irrelevant')
                End If

                previousFrameMAT = CurrentFrameMAT.Clone()     ' Update frame objects by saving previous frame and querying a new one
                CurrentFrameMAT = fingerprintCapture.QueryFrame()

                frameCount += 1
            End While

        End Using
    Next

End Sub
```

While debugging,  the CurrentFrameMAT stays nothing.

Any advice on how to read the frames sequentially?

I have seen a function called Grab() and retrieve pertaining to the capture object but could not get it to work.  Where would one start the process?

```
fingerprintCapture.Start()
fingerprintCapture.Grab() 'Grab a frame
fingerprintCapture.Retrieve() 'Gray image after Grab()
```

Any advice or a link to an implementation of the new Emgu version on video / webcam capture would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In C#, I solve this problem by adding the opencv_ffmpeg300.dll
If the dll is not here there is no error message and the number of frames is 0. But after adding the dll, I got my frames and can process them.